# Responsively Center Sidebar On Mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

On a tablet or laptop, a post and sidebar will appear with the post either left or right while the sidebar will be the opposite.  For example:

```
Sidebar | Post
```

... or ...

```
Post | Sidebar
```

The trouble is with mobile - the post in example one or the sidebar in example two will appear left-aligned, when I want them center-stacked.  I can't give each of them a width of 100% - even though on mobile, that is what I would want.

I did try a few techniques with centering divs; for an example I thought I could use a responsive div approach with the post or sidebar like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8"><!-- POST --></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8"><!-- SIDEBAR --></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

... or vice versa where the post is centered with the sidebar on top.  In both cases, on mobile, the centered div (`col-md-8`) is still left aligned.

Just to visualize the goal, on a laptop or tablet, it would appear like:

```
Sidebar | Post
```

or

```
Post | Sidebar
```

On a mobile, it would appear like:

```
Sidebar-Centered
Post-Centered
```

**Update:**

Tested with the `xs` for mobile:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8"><!-- POST --></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8"><!-- SIDEBAR --></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In theory, that should have assisted on mobile, but still no dice.

Answer (score 1):

There would be an issue with your css nothing else.
You can fix it with the css.

For more help, could you please share the link of your webpage? So that we can configure out what exactly problem is.